# Unable to identify the object from ruby library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, feature-file

I recently updated the OS to ELcaptain and ever since my feature files are failing and not identifying object.

This is the error I get in terminal when I run a file:

```
cannot load such file -- rspec (LoadError)
/Users/xyz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
/Users/xyz/ttv-cucumber/helper/auto_loader.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xyz/ttv-cucumber/flow-combo-selection/features/support/common.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/Users/xyzr/ttv-cucumber/flow-combo-selection/features/support/common.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:99:in `load'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:99:in `load_code_file'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:232:in `load_file'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:99:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:98:in `each'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:98:in `load_files!'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:262:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:65:in `run!'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:32:in `execute!'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/bin/cucumber:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

And on the step definitions I get this error:

```
undefined method `expect' for #<Object:0x007fb6b1d1ac80> (NoMethodError)
```

This is my gem list:

```
appium_lib (8.0.0, 4.1.0)
awesome_print (1.6.1)
bigdecimal (1.2.7, 1.2.4)
blankslate (3.1.3, 2.1.2.4)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
childprocess (0.5.8, 0.5.6)
chunky_png (1.3.5, 1.3.4)
coderay (1.1.0)
cucumber (2.0.0)
cucumber-core (1.3.0, 1.1.3)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
ffi (1.9.10, 1.9.8)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
gherkin (2.12.2)
gherkin3 (3.1.2)
io-console (0.4.3)
jar_wrapper (0.1.8)
json (1.8.3, 1.8.1)
method_source (0.8.2)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.8.2, 4.7.5)
multi_json (1.11.1)
multi_test (0.1.2)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
parslet (1.5.0)
power_assert (0.2.6)
pry (0.10.1)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
rmagick (2.15.2)
rspec (3.3.0)
rspec-core (3.3.0)
rspec-expectations (3.3.0)
rspec-mocks (3.3.0)
rspec-support (3.3.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubytest (0.8.1)
rubyzip (1.1.7)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
selenium (0.2.11)
selenium-cucumber (2.1.3)
selenium-webdriver (2.45.0)
slop (3.6.0)
test (1.0.0)
test-unit (2.1.6.0)
toml (0.1.2)
websocket (1.2.2)
zip (2.0.2)
```

Comment: where are you using `expect`? show some code YOU wrote.

Comment: I am using  expect().to for verifying result which require 'rspec'. This is my step definition Then(/^I see title in loop qual page "(.*?)"$/) do |message|
expect(loop_qual_page.title).to include message
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this if you haven't already:

run `bundle install`

If you do not have a spec helper or rails helper in the spec directory, run this: `rails generate rspec:install`

Comment: This is what I get after I try to run                                                             2.1.6 :001 > bundle install
NameError: undefined local variable or method `install' for main:Object
 from (irb):1
 from /Users/Xyz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.1.6 :002 > rails generate rspec:install
NameError: undefined local variable or method `install' for main:Object
 from (irb):2
 from /Users/Xyz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.1.6 :003 > exit

Comment: try this: 'rvm @global do gem install bundler' and then try again 'bundle install'. Your gems are not installed, that seems to be a problem. The first command will install a global bundler gem, which will enable you to install other gems in the gemset (if you are using one) or globally, if you aren't.